# Running karma on team city - "cannot find module"

Tags: node.js, teamcity, karma-runner

I'm new to node. I'm trying to run javascript tests on TeamCity using nodejs+karma+jasmine.

I have installed node on both my local development machine and on TeamCity. It seems to be working at both places.

I have made a local install of karma using `npm install karma` and configured it using `.\node_modules\.bin\karma.cmd init`. The tests run fine locally using `.\node_modules\.bin\karma.cmd start --single-run`
. I have checked in the whole node_module folder.

When I try to run karma in TeamCity using a command line step that runs `.\node_modules\.bin\karma.cmd start --single-run` I get the following:

```
[08:52:42][Step 6/6] module.js:340
[08:52:42][Step 6/6]     throw err;
[08:52:42][Step 6/6]           ^
[08:52:42][Step 6/6] Error: Cannot find module 'D:\tc_a1\work\c4418f0fd0a402a7\node_modules\karma\bin\karma'
[08:52:42][Step 6/6]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
[08:52:42][Step 6/6]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
[08:52:42][Step 6/6]     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
[08:52:42][Step 6/6]     at startup (node.js:119:16)
[08:52:42][Step 6/6]     at node.js:901:3
```

I have tried several permutations of the run command, but they all result in the same output.

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was wrong was that my git checkin of the karma module was not complete.

My `.gitignore` file ended like this

```
!node_modules
```

But that still ignored some files in subdirectories that matched other ignore patterns. When we changed the ending of `.gitignore` to this

```
!node_modules/**
```

Then we found those files, committed them, and it started working

Answer (score 0):

What does the directory structure look like on the TeamCity agent at `D:\tc_a1\work\c4418f0fd0a402a7`? Is your `node_modules` folder present?

We have it running in TeamCity with Karma copied to a folder outside the of the user profile (where globally installed npm packages go), and then added to the path so it can be run without providing the whole path.